# promise.all on a partial array of promises executes the original array instead

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

Here's the code (it's a simple test, to see how this works so I can apply it to a larger work project):

```
async function wait(seconds) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, seconds * 1000));
}

async function printer(seconds) {
  await wait(seconds);
  console.log("Hello");
}

async function main() {
  const list = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    list.push(printer(i));
  }

  list.splice(0, 3);

  await Promise.all(list);
}

main();
```

Desired behavior: Hello gets printed 7 times
Actual behavior: Hello gets printed 10 times

Comment: Hello gets printed 10 times because the for loop runs 10 times which calls `printer' which console.logs hello

Comment: You don't "execute" promises. Promises are a just a notification mechanism for an already running async task. So if you have a promise, there is a task running. Awaiting or not awaiting the promise does not affect the task. Not awaiting only means you do not get to act when it finishes. However, it will still finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than invoking each `printer` function when creating our list of promises, we can create a list of N functions, each with its own delay in seconds (from 1 to 10).

Once we've created our list of 10 functions, we can splice to drop the required amount, then call each function in turn to create our list of 7 promises.

Finally we can await the results by calling Promise.all().

```js
async function wait(seconds) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, seconds * 1000));
}

function createPrinter(seconds) {
    return () => printer(seconds);
}

async function printer(seconds) {
  await wait(seconds)
  console.log("Hello");
}

async function main() {
  const list = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    list.push(createPrinter(i));
  }

  list.splice(0, 3);

  const promises = list.map(fn => fn());
  await Promise.all(promises);
}

main();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

As @VLAZ says in the comments, you are expecting a `Promise` to be something you execute, rather than what it is, just a notification mechanism that tells you if a piece of code has executed (and the code executes whether you check on the `Promise` or not).

When you call `printer(i)` the `wait()` function is called before your `splice()` method call can do anything to reduce the number of `printer` functions. So all of them execute, giving you 10 results.

If you want to postpone starting the waiting code until a time of your choosing, you need to rewrite in a way that allows to you to trigger the waiting. Here is a way which turns the `printer` functions into objects which you can then trigger after you have reduced the size of the array:

```js
function wait(seconds) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, seconds * 1000));
}

class Printer {
  constructor(seconds) {
    this.seconds = seconds
  }

  async printAfterDelay() {
    await wait(this.seconds);
    console.log("Hello", this.seconds);
  }
}

async function main() {
  const list = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    list.push(new Printer(i));
  }

  list.splice(0, 3);

  const printingPromises = list.map(
    printd => printd.printAfterDelay() // starts the waiting
  )

  await Promise.all(printingPromises); // This code doesn't really do anything as there is no more code to execute
}

main();
```

Comment: `list.forEach` should be `list.map` (otherwise `printingPromises` would be undefined)

Comment: very true. updated.